# make decorator Only the creator of Content can manipulate it

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have created Two decorator to block anyone to Access to specific content
like:

```
   @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='core:login'), name='dispatch')
   @method_decorator(allowed_users(allowed_roles=['writer']), name='dispatch')
    class BookDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
        model = Book
        template_name = 'book/book_delete.html'
        success_message = 'Success: book was deleted.'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('core:book_list')
```

i want to create decorator seems like this

```
book=Book.objects.get(id=pk)
if request.user==book.writer.profile.user:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a decorator:

```
def writers_only(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user == Book.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('pk')).writer.profile.user:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # Do something else 
  return wrap
```

Then add this to your class based view:

```
# Other decorators
@method_decorator(writers_only, name='dispatch')
class BookDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
    # Your code
```

Otherwise you can also override `BookDeleteView.get_object` (you can create a mixin to reuse this implementation of `get_object` in various views):

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='core:login'), name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(allowed_users(allowed_roles=['writer']), name='dispatch')
    class BookDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
        model = Book
        template_name = 'book/book_delete.html'
        success_message = 'Success: book was deleted.'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('core:book_list')
        
        def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
            obj = super().get_object(*args, **kwargs)
            if obj.writer.profile.user != self.request.user:
                raise PermissionDenied() # Or do something else
            return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a decorator for that. What you need is `queryset` defined on your model view that will restrict the query:

```
class BookDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
    def get_queryset(self):        
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

In case it has to be done for delete only you may also set it dynamically depending on request:

```
class BookDeleteView(BSModalDeleteView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'DELETE':        
            return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return self.model.objects.all()
```